# read nested arrays from json string in Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I am facing a problem will reading a json string containing nested arrays.

```
{
    "invoiceSet": {
        "lines": [
            {
                "line": "Business Partner had two or more interactions in the last 30 days",
                "togState": "true",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "linktxt": "Interaction History",
                        "linkid": "IRHIST"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "line": "Open CRC Complaints Exist",
                "togState": "false",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "linktxt": "Interaction History",
                        "linkid": "IRHIST"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "line": "Open Complaints Exist",
                "togState": "true",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "linktxt": "Interaction History",
                        "linkid": "IRHIST"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "line": "Business Partner is a landlord",
                "togState": "false",
                "links": []
            },
            {
                "line": "Remotes Business Partner",
                "togState": "true",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "linktxt": "Interaction History",
                        "linkid": "IRHIST"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "line": "Recent move has occurred in the last 60 days",
                "togState": "false",
                "links": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using ajax call to get this json in a string

```
var setJsonText = jQuery.ajax({ url: ajxUrl,
                                            cache: false,
                                            async: false,
                                            type:"POST",
                                            dataType: "html" }).responseText;
var sets = jQuery.parseJSON( setJsonText );

viewModel.invLines(sets.invoiceSet.lines)
```

And my viewmodel

```
var viewModel = {
           invLines: ko.observableArray([]),
};
```

HTML

```
<table width="100%" >
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: invLines" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
   <td data-bind="text: line"></td>
   <td>
    <ul data-bind="foreach:links">
     <li>
      <a><span  data-bind="text:linktxt"></span></a>
     </li>
    </ul>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The line are getting correctly printed but problem in coming on corresponding links. Please let me know what m i doing wrong.

Thanks,
Anshul Kaistha

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be in your ajax call. Why are you getting the data as HTML and then converting it to JSON? Why not just get the data as JSON?

Anyway, this jsFiddle demonstrates your code working (minus the ajax call) so all your bindings as you posted seem valid:

http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/g9Q9V/3/

Hope this helps solve your problem.

Comment: ok ill look into it.

One more issue i m facing i want to call a javascipt function on click of a link and pass linkid as parameter in that function . i am not able to pass linkid as parameter could u help me with this.

<ul data-bind="foreach:links">
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:callMyparentWithParam(event,'{{links.linkid }}','{{ linktxt }}')";>
<span  data-bind="text:linktxt"></span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: If you want to pass parts of your view model in a click event you would be well advised to look at the click binding on the knockout website: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html Otherwise, I would post it as a seperate question as the comments on stackoverflow aren't really designed for long discussions.